# How to test external url or links in a django website?

Tags: python, django, testing, web-scraping, external-links

Hi I am building a blogging website in django 1.8 with python 3. In the blog users will write blogs and sometimes add external links. 
I want to crawl all the pages in this blog website and test every external link provided by the users is valid or not.

How can i do this? Should i use something like python scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
import fnmatch

def site_checker(url):

    url_chk = url.split('/')
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(url_chk[0], 'http*'):
        url = url
    else:
        url = 'http://%s' %(url)
    print url

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        if response:
            print 'site is legit'
    except Exception:
    print "not a legit site yo!"

site_checker('google') ## not a complete url
site_checker('http://google.com') ## this works
```

Hopefully this works. Urllib will read the html of the site and if its not empty. It's a legit site. Else it's not a site. Also I added a url check to add http:// if its not there.